# Lifetime of argument affected by local class : possible pitfalls?

Tags: java, arguments, inner-classes

The other day I was concerned with lifetime of arguments in a code looking like :

```java
    void someMethod(final ComplexObject arg1, ComplexObject arg2) {

        // .. some code

        // new instance of Runnable is executed on another thread
        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { // note: arg2 is not referenced inside run()
                // 1
                // .. some code here
                arg1.doStuff();
                // 2
                //.. some extra code here
            }   // 3
        });
    }
```

considering call:

```java
someMethod(new ComplexObject(), // object1
        new ComplexObject()); // object2
```

I assume that newly created `object1` can only be `GC`'ed  when another thread(s) is done with `run` method (line //3).
And obviously `object2` is not affected in this case.

1. Could someone please confirm these assumptions, and also
2. Are there practical scenario's (example) when one should be wary of such unpredictable lifetime extension of `object1` creating possibility of a "leak" ? (which is especially undesired if `ComplexObject` is a "heavy" memory object)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that when the `Runnable()` you have created has is GCed the `arg1` will also be GCed and not before that, as GC knows which object holds reference to which objects.

I won't call that a leak, as leak occurs when unwanted references are held in the memory, but here you need those references.

Comment: +1 anyways, thanks for confirmation of lifetime of arg1. I guess this is due to the fact that arg1 is compiled as a member of anonymous Rannabls (in the bytecode), so it makes sense that they die in that order.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is quite hard to right code in Java which has chaotic memory leaks. You are right, the GC keeps a reference counter on each object and the object is not applicable for GC until the reference count is back to 0.

Practical scenarios.....Oddly I canno think of any truly obvious examples other than doing ridiculous stuff on purpose like making .clone() of the heavy object and keeping references to them for no purpose other than to cause a leak!

Comment: In fact in Java, cyclic references are recognized and GCed as well. So the reference count statement isn't correct.

Comment: Well, I honestly don't think it is a good answer either. You can have a memory leak on android relatively easily, and that is where posted code was originated.

Comment: @kiruwka you are confusing out of memory with memory leak.

Comment: @NarendraPathai No, I am not :). I had experience with both of them and not saying that this piece of code creates a memleak by itself. I am asking for a scenario that might create it. (may be runnable sumbitted to some broken "executor" which will keep it static or longer than needed ?

Comment: Yes statics are evil. You have to trust the API you are using. Executor in Java will never create a leak.